# How can I identify a step in an increasing time series?

Tags: r, time-series, structural-change

The time series data, as shown in image 1, has 3 separate steps connected by increasing data. How do I detect these steps?[image]

An easier set of data with one step could be created in R as follows:

```
x <- seq(1,220)
y <- c(seq(1,100),rep(100, times = 20),seq(101,200))
plot(x,y)
```

The output is shown in image 2. How would I detect this step? I think a solution to this simple problem would be similar to finding the steps in the earlier dataset.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways. For the sample with R code, it's as simple as differencing then analyzing the new series, e.g. see this code and the plot:

```
dy=diff(y)
plot(x[2:length(x)],dy)
```

[image]

This may not work for the real data though, if the data generating process is different from your sample code.

Comment: It does turn into a step problem if I smooth it first using moving averages. Would you happen to know how I find the optimum window size for moving averages? For example, how do I defend using a window size of 5% of the data vs 10% of the data?

Comment: I don't think that the window size can be wider than the step width.

Comment: @SPV: A rolling mean is essentially a low pass filter. That is, it attenuates the amplitude of frequencies above a certain point. A filter like this can therefore be used to smooth out high frequency noise, while retaining a lower frequency signal. In general terms, you want the window to be of a length so that it attenuates as much noise as possible, without distorting the signal you are interested in. As such Aksakal's tip is a reasonable one.